# PHP/SQL script to increment value of a record field is not updating the record

Tags: php, mysql

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value=95 /> A<br />
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value=85 /> B<br />
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value=75 /> C<br />
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value=65 /> D<br />
    <input type="radio" name="grade" value=50 /> F
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['grade'])) {
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $grade = $_POST['grade'];
                    $sql = "UPDATE grade SET 
                    total=total+'$grade',
                    numvotes=numvotes+1 WHERE
                    name='$name'";
```

Hi everyone... I'm working on a project to add grades associated with names on a menu. My HTML code for the radial menu for the grade is above and my relevant SQL is shown as well. I want to add a NUMBER VALUE from the grade onto the "total" in my SQL database and increase the number of votes by 1. I'm not sure if my syntax is correct because the database neither gets an addition to its votes or grade total.
Thanks!

EDIT: Part of the reason why I'm confused that this doesn't work is b/c when I go into the mySQL console, I can do an almost identical command (where instead '$grade' is a number) and it works. In the least I should get an error or maybe the numvotes should increase, but nothing.

EDIT2: Credit to Radu for catching this. My name menu doesn't function properly. After using $die after my SQL statement, I found that the names being selected from the dropdown menu were being interpreted as integers, not names. It is to be populated by the SQL names in the database. Here is my code.

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT name, id FROM grade");
    echo "<select name='name'>";
        while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            echo "<option value='".$temp['name']."'>".$temp['name']."    </option>";
        }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

EDIT3: After changing    `$temp['id']` to `$temp['name']`, I found that my `die($sql)` now reads:

```
UPDATE grade SET total=total+'95', numvotes=numvotes+1 WHERE name='charlie'
```

So the name is going in, but it's STILL not getting updated. Ideas?

Comment: Your class will have straight A's with that code.

Comment: Why not save each submission with name and score, then you can count how many scores were submitted by name and total the scores with one simple query.

Comment: A minor note - the value attribute in your `<input>` tags should be quoted.  In fact, all HTML attributes get quotes.

Comment: @ryan: A good point, but then there would be a LOT of redundancy in my database. As it built up, there would be thousands of grades associated with the same name.

Comment: @Tory Waterman it's not redundacy, it's data :)

Comment: I notice you are building a query in `$sql`; does your code actually send that query to your database (e.g., `mysql_query()`)?  If so, could you edit the listing in your question to include this code?

Comment: Just a minor note: you _do_ run `$sql` through `mysql_query` don't you? You wouldn't be the first to have a query ready but forgetting to actually execute it :) (and if so: show use `mysql_error();`)

Comment: @surreal: also a good point, though does it make a difference? I'm fairly new to HTML... does it actually change the way the value is interpreted?

Comment: Also, don't forget to escape the input, which you may have left off for simplicity reasons.

Comment: @phoenix, wrikken: yes, i do query it afterwards. sorry for not clarifying it, it's a snippet.
@ryan: does the "/" at the end of the input declaration not escape it? I'm new to html and could be completely making a fool of myself with that statement

Comment: @Tory: in this case it's probably not going to affect your situation.  It's just a rule for well-formed XHTML.  However, if the document got more complex, you start doing client-side scripting, who knows.  Better to make the code right now than pull your hair out later.

Comment: Why is $grade in quotes when it's an integer?

Comment: @AR: a valid point, I changed that and it doesn't seem to have affected anything.

Comment: @Tory Waterman you'd want to use something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: The things wrong with that code are not few. But to debug your specific problem, use a `die($sql)` just after you compose it, then copy paste the exact query in your MySQL client to see what happens.

Comment: @ryan that doesnt seem to have any effect either, thank you for pointing that out as well though.

Comment: @Tory Waterman that wasn't regarding the problem you posted about, but definitely something to do

Comment: @Radu: I think we found the problem.     
It outputs: UPDATE grade SET total=total+'95', numvotes=numvotes+1 WHERE name='2';
Now what would cause the name to be equal to '2' and not someone's name?

Comment: @Radu it's simply a project for demonstration, not live use. I've posted the code that could be causing this problem above.

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` if you suspect it being syntax.

Comment: @Tony Waterman, alright, if you won't be putting this live with real users, then you should be fine.

Comment: RE edit 3:  If `temp` is, for instance, 5, then `temp + '95'` will give you `'595'`, not `100`.

Comment: Folks - you know we have a cracking chat room feature that makes discussion like this way more easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using names as strings in the SQL query. So change the following:

```
echo "<option value='".$temp['id']."'>".$temp['name']."</option>";
```

to:

```
echo "<option>".htmlspecialchars($temp['name'])."</option>";
```

For live projects, *always* use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when `echo()`ing something to the browser, and *always* use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) when composing SQL queries from user input.

For example, in a live project, you should always use `$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])` instead of simply `$name = $_POST['name']`.

Comment: You're welcome. Just don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` in real, live projects. There will only be benefits from doing this.

Comment: @Tory @Radu: Actually in real, live projects, you shouldn't be concatenating SQL strings at all; you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.  There is then no chance of you accidentally forgetting to escape a string.

Answer (score 3):

remove `,` after

```
numvotes=numvotes+1
```

in your query

Comment: That seems like it should work, but I still get the same behavior. I have changed that, however. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
USERS
-----
id AUTO_INCREMENT
name

VOTES
-----
id AUTO_INCREMENT
user_id
grade

INSERT INTO votes (user_id, grade) VALUES (1, 95);
INSERT INTO votes (user_id, grade) VALUES (1, 85);
INSERT INTO votes (user_id, grade) VALUES (2, 75);
```

Then to get vote count for first user:

```
SELECT count(*) total_votes FROM votes WHERE user_id = 1;
```

And to get score:

```
SELECT sum(grade) total_score FROM votes WHERE user_id = 1;
```

This is untested, but should get you on the right track.

Comment: It basically stores information about the user. Then if anything ever changes about a user, such as the name, your queries will still be valid and you'll get all the votes from that user. It prevents data anomalies.

Comment: This might arguably be a better way to store the data; unfortunately it does not address the OP's problem that his SQL does not appear to be getting executed on the database.

Comment: @Phoenix true, but storing it this way does ultimately give me him the results he wants.

Comment: The code I originally posted works, though the way I work my dropdown menu is flawed. Please see above.

Answer (score 1):

it might just be an oversight in your example, but the  tag should be

```
<form method="post">
```

otherwise this condition will never trigger, as forms default to using GET method

```
if (isset($_POST['grade'])) {
```